# Rails allow access to one page without restricting the whole controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have 3 types of users:

```
admin
moderator
regular user
```

I have the moderator and admin pages locked with a controller-wide system like this:

```
def authorize
  unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) and User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).moderator == true
    redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Please log in with a moderator account"
  end
end

def authorize_admin
  unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) and User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).admin == 1
    redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Only admins can access the page you tried to access"
  end
end
```

But I need to give access to the regular user to the edit pages (and of course the update action) of multiple controllers. But just edit and update.

If I do:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => :edit
```

Then anyone (even if not logged in) has access to those pages.

How would I go about doing something like that?

**Edit**

As per Thilo's suggestion, I added the following to the application_controller.erb file:

```
  def update_successful
    skip_before_filter :authorize
  end
```

To be able to serve the update_successful page after a regular user has edited an entry. However I get this error:

```
undefined method `skip_before_filter' for #<HomeController:0x007ff782aeb6f0>
```

Comment: How are you currently using those two methods? As a `before_filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip any globally applies filter explicitly:

```
skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

Or don't apply it to the relevant actions in the first place:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:edit, :update]
```

**EDIT**

To answer your further question: Add this to your application controller:

```
def upload_successful
end
```

This is an empty method that explicitly defines the action that so far as been implicitly be used by Rails when rendering the `home/upload_successful.html.haml` template. Then, remove authentication from that method by modifying your filter:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:upload_successful]
```

Here's a good [introduction to rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) in Rails - it helps to understand rendering by default, which is what your `upload_successful` template has been displayed without having a matching controller or action defined.

Comment: But this way, anyone can see these pages without even having an account. I did what you suggest and also added a `before_filter :authorize_user` (which checks that a regular user is logged in) to every controller that has the edit and update methods. Not sure if this is the right way to do it, still having some problems with it.

Comment: Also, I have a page that I want the regular users to be redirected to after a successful update. I tried putting: `skip_before_filter :authorize` in the view (haml template) but that doesn't seem to work. It's just a regular page that sits in the 'home' directory with no controller. How can I let them access that page? (thanks for the replies BTW).

Comment: Filters go on controllers, and every action has one - if not explicitly, then the default `ApplicationController`. Just add an (empty) method to that with the name of your page, and set the filter for that.

Comment: Sorry Thilo, I don't understand what you mean by 'Just add an (empty) method to that with the name of your page, and set the filter for that'. What is 'that' in this context?

Comment: Your `ApplicationController` class.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it, you're saying in `applicationController` set an empty method for the update_successful.html.haml page? Can you give me an example of how it would be?

Comment: I think I finally understood what you are saying, please see edit in main post.